# Prevent leaving the whole table selected after applying autofilter on inactive sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 tables in 3 different sheets and they act as a relational database (I know, I know... The beauty of legacy systems). When clicking on a row a form opens and data is entered, no problem in that.

The last step of my data handling is sorting the table with autofilter, which works perfectly well. If the table is in the ActiveSheet, then my ActiveCell is the same as before starting the macro, which is ok. But if the table is in any other sheet then, when returning to the tables sheet, the whole DataBodyRange is selected.

My current approach as for now is to look if the ActiveSheet is different from the tables sheet and, if so, select the 1st cell of the table.

I would like to select the "active cell" of that sheet instead of the 1st one.

- All my tables are ListObjects
- This only happens if the Autofilter is applied on an inactive sheet
- I am using fully qualified ranges

```
dim lo as ListObject
'lo is my tables ListObject

dim rg as Range
set rg = ActiveCell

'do stuff
lo.Sort.Apply '<-- Table is sorted, last step of my handling

'Here I handle 
if rg.parent.name = lo.parent.name then
' do nothing
else
 lo.Parent.Activate
 lo.DataBodyRange(1,1).Select
 rg.Parent.Activate
 rg.select
end
```

Question:

Is there an alternative to `ActiveCell` that picks up the "active" cell of an inactive sheet?

If so, I assume I can use it instead of the line `lo.DataBodyRange(1,1).Select`?

Comment: If you show the whole code it might help.

Comment: All the relevant information is there. But I will rephrase the question.

Comment: You can turn off screenupdating, select the sheet, record the selection, then switch back to the original sheet.  That could all be wrapped up in a function.